# Building a class in python with mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am making a database class in python to help with managing my mysql database.

The code below works until the last line

```
import MySQLdb

class Database:
    ...

    def insert(self, query):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            self.connection.commit()
        except:
            self.connection.rollback()
    ...

db = Database()
db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES ("tester2");')
mystring = "TEST"
db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);', mystring)
```

The last line causes the error:

```
    db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);', mystring)
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have tried to rearrange the contents inside the db.insert's parens but I cannot figure out the syntax.

For instance I have tried this as well, but it neither inserts nor gives an error:

```
db.insert('''"INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);", mystring''')
```

My question is can I get the syntax right in order to insert using the %s, or do I have to change my class's insert function?

**EDIT 1**

I have tried the suggested lines:

```
db.insert("INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);"% mystring)
```

and

```
db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES {value};'.format(value=mystring))
```

neither gave errors nor inputed any value into the database

**EDIT 2**

Whole code for main that calls the Database class:

if **name** == "**main**":

```
db = Database()
mystring = 'Tester1'
mystring2 = 'Tester2'
db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES ("Tester3");')  #works
db.insert("INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);" % mystring) #does not work
db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES {value};'.format(value=mystring2)) #does not work
print db.query('SELECT * FROM items;')
```

Comment: you just want to pass in the string

Comment: `db = Database`  where's the parentheses ?

Comment: @haifzhan you're right, fixed it, (it was correct in my code)

Comment: @Rorschach see my edit. you have to invoke `execute` correctly

Comment: can you print the exception you're getting change your exception to `except Exception as e` and add `print e` before rollback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

The issue you have is not only passing one argument. but also invoking `execute()` incorrectly:

```
insert_stat ="INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
# execute() takes 2 arguments, first is the statement as above, second argument is a tuple which contains all values
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

In your case, it should be something look like:
`self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);', (mystring,))`

**Original Answer:**

You need to pass only one argument `query`. Therefore you can format your query as one string like this:

`'INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES {value};'.format(value=mystring)`

change
`db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);', mystring)`
to
`db.insert('INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES {value};'.format(value=mystring))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`db.insert("INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);" % mystring)`
Basically you want `mystring` to be part of the query string, not a separate parameter.

Comment: that gave: db.insert('"INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s);"% mystring)
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Whoops extra quote, sorry on the phone, remove first quote. See updated answer.